# How to change Gmail profile picture without using Google+

Tags: gmail, google-account-profile

I want to change my profile picture on Gmail, but I can't use Google+ since it's my school email account. I've been looking for a way to change my profile pic, and maybe one of you can help me. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google+ has been discontinued.

Answer (score 5):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?hl=en):

> 1. Click the gear in the top right.
> 2. Select **Settings**.
> 3. From the **My picture** section, click **Select a picture**. The **Upload a picture** window will appear.
> 4. Upload a new photo from your computer, or select a photo from Picasa Web Albums or your previous Google profile photos.
> 5. A box will appear over your photo, selecting part of it. Drag this selected region to crop your photo, or resize the region by clicking and dragging one of the region corners.
> 6. Click **Apply Changes**.
> 7. You can select whether you'd like all Gmail users to see your picture, or only those who you've allowed to chat with you, using the radio buttons next to your uploaded photo on your Settings page.
>
>    - **Visible to everyone** means anyone who you email, or who emails you, can see your picture.
>    - **Visible only to people I can chat with** includes users who have been given permission to see when you're online and to chat with you.
>
> Once you apply your picture, you'll be able to view and change it from your **Gmail settings** page, and other users will see your selection when they roll over your name in conversations or in their contact lists. It will also show up as your picture in chat (Google Chat or Hangouts). Likewise, picture selections made in chat will be reflected in your Gmail interface, though there might be a slight delay for the change to take effect.